# Django Admin Change List template

Tags: django-admin

I have this model:

```
class IllnessMedication(models.Model):
  FREQUENCY_CHOICES = (
    ('D', 'Day'),
    ('W', 'Week'),
    ('M', 'Month'),
  )

  NUMERIC_CHOICES = (
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (4, 4),
  )

  illness = models.ForeignKey(Illness)
  medication = models.ForeignKey(Medication)
  strength = models.CharField("strength", max_length=25)
  dosage = models.IntegerField("dosage", choices=NUMERIC_CHOICES)

  class Meta:
    db_table = "medication_illness"

class Medication(models.Model):
  value = models.CharField("medication", max_length=50)

  class Meta:
    db_table = "medication"

class Illness(models.Model):
  value = models.CharField("code", max_length=10)
  description = models.CharField("description", max_length=100)

  class Meta:
    db_table = "illness"
```

I want to display the list view in group by fashion, i.e.

```
Illness1
   Medication11
      Strenght1    Dosage1
      Strenght2    Dosage2
      Strenght3    Dosage3

  Medication12
     Strenght1    Dosage1
     Strenght2    Dosage2
     Strenght3    Dosage3

Illness2
   Medication21
      Strenght1    Dosage1
      ..................
```

Is this possible to achieve by tweaking the django admin Model and ModelAdmin using available Django installed options/features/etc or I should expect to commit serious effort to overwrite the change_list.html template?

If the latter is true, please give me some pointers.  Muchly appreciated.

Nghi

Comment: couldn't you just show the medication details on another page. just wondering.

Comment: sorry for late response.  I can, but still wonder if this is possible.

Comment: Just a hack: what about creating a singleton class that contains all the illness and show the desired information as Inlines?
You can use [django-admin-singleton](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-singleton-admin/)